# Most efficient SQL for this example

Tags: sql

```
Table A: Person: id, name
Table B: Toys: id, person_id, toy_name
```

I have a search screen that includes a dropdown of fixed toy names.
A search is found if a subset of the total set of toys for a person is matched.

Example, a person name=bob has toys: doll, car, house, hat

A search is done for person name=bob and toys=doll, hat.

I want to return bob and ALL of his toys, not just what toys were searched for(doll, hat).
Bob is found because a subset of his toys are a match.

I don't know what the most efficient/least db calls way to accomplish this.
I can do a search for bob and get all of his toys, then parse through the result set to see if the searched for toys find a match, but that seems wrong, that the db call could return rows for which no match is found (and that seems wrong?).

Comment: which SQL engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using a subquery and checking for the existence of Hat and Doll in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select p.id, p.name, 
  t.id as toyid, t.name as toyname
from person p
  inner join toys t on p.id = t.person_id
  inner join (
    select person_id
    from toys 
    group by person_id
    having sum(name = 'hat') > 0 and
      sum(name = 'doll') > 0
    ) t2 on p.id = t2.person_id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5353/1)

Comment: forgot to ask...i do not see how "t2" comes into play, would you explain a bit?

Comment: "t2" is the alias for the clause "inner join(select person..." ?

Comment: @bmw0128 -- no worries, glad I could help.  But yes, t2 is just an alias for the subquery to ensure the person has both hat and doll.  Best regards.

Comment: does the sum part like you have it work in Oracle, when I try to run in Oracle, i get the "missing right paranthesis" error?

Answer (score 2):

okay,

```
select
  p.id,
  p.name, 
  t.id as toyid, 
  t.toy_name
from 
     person p
  join
     toys t
        on p.id = t.person_id
where
     p.id in (
        select person_id from toys where toy_name = 'doll'
        intersect
        select person_id from toys where toy_name = 'hat');
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aed4a/1)

---

If you normalise your schema a little further,

```
create table Person
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(100)
);

create table Toy
(
    Id int, 
    Name varchar(100)
);

create table PersonToy
(
    Id int,
    PersonId int,
    ToyId int
);
```

It should make the complexity of the problem clearer. It will also save some space. A statement of the form,

```
select
            p.Name PersonName,
            t.Name ToyName
    from
            Person p
        join
            PersonToy pt
                on pt.PersonId = p.Id
        join
            Toy t
                on t.Id = pt.ToyId
    where
        p.Id in
        (
            select PersonId from PersonToy where ToyId = 1
            intersect
            select PersonId from PersonToy where ToyId = 4
        );
```

will work efficiently.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67282/2)

Comment: i'll check this one, you're saying this is more efficient?

Comment: @bmw0128, generally group bys with havings have poor performance.

Comment: good info, thx...your SQL is close, but not exactly what i need, if i add "name = 'hat'or name='doll'" where @searchParam is, only bob should return, for jane does not have a doll, so she should not return. I'll try to make it so, unless you know?

Comment: @bmw0128 I've changed the code to use the `intersect` of the two sets. The intersect keyword is part of the SQL92 standard but may not be implemented on some SQL engines (like mysql).

Comment: does it bother you that this solution has two selects, and one select for each toy name? If many toy names, many selects. Does that negate the efficiency over the group by/having solution?

Comment: @bmw0128, the number of sub queries does not bother me. I've included a more normalised schema and fiddle that runs on oracle. The only way to know which is faster is to try both on your engine and data.